# Which partitions are important?

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, backup

I'm currently using Windows 10, but I'd love to work with a dual boot with Ubuntu Linux. I'm a little confused what all these partitions are and which of them are important for Windows booting normally.

I'm a little lost and almost just deleted everything and installed only Linux as I thought this might be a little easier.

Perhaps someone has an idea if it's a problem having that many partitions. Sorry for them being in German.

[image: Partitions]

Comment: You can run DISKPART https://ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html to see a list of disks and of partitions in text form, instead of graphically, which is easier to post here once you copy the text.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you have a BIOS or UEFI motherboard:

- **BIOS**: Two partitions are *required*: Boot & OS

  ```powershell
  DISKPART> sel dis 0
  Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

  DISKPART> lis par
    Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
    -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
    Partition 2    System             100 MB   666 MB
    Partition 3    Primary            300 GB   767 MB


  Partition 2
  Type    : 0x07
  Hidden  : Yes
  Required: No

    Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
    ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    Volume 12        Boot          NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System


  Partition 3
  Type    : 0x07
  Hidden  : No
  Required: No

    Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
    ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    Volume 8     C   System       NTFS   Partition    300 GB  Healthy    Boot
  ```

  - Three partitions are *recommended*: WinRE, Boot, & OS 
     *WinRE (**Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment) should be on its own partition, else, if corruption occurs on the OS partition that affects `WinRE.wim`, Recovery cannot be booted to*

    ```powershell
    DISKPART> sel dis 0
    Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

    DISKPART> lis par
      Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
      -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
      Partition 1    Recovery           665 MB  1024 KB


    Partition 1
    Type    : 0x27
    Hidden  : Yes
    Required: Yes

      Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
      ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
      Volume 14        WinRE        NTFS   Partition    665 MB   Healthy    Hidden
    ```
- **UEFI:** Four partitions are *required*: WinRE, EFI, MSR, & OS

  ```powershell
  DISKPART> sel dis 0
  Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

  DISKPART> lis par
    Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
    -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
    Partition 1    Recovery          2560 MB  1024 KB
    Partition 2    System             260 MB  2561 MB
    Partition 3    Reserved           128 MB  2821 MB
    Partition 4    Primary            300 GB  2949 MB


  DISKPART> sel par 1
  Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

  DISKPART> det par
  Partition 1
  Type    : de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
  Hidden  : No
  Required: Yes
  Attrib  : 0X8000000000000001
  Offset in Bytes: 1048576

    Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
    ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  * Volume 14        WinRE        NTFS   Partition   2560 MB  Healthy    Hidden


  DISKPART> sel par 2
  Partition 2 is now the selected partition.

  DISKPART> det par
  Partition 2
  Type    : c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
  Hidden  : Yes
  Required: No
  Attrib  : 0X8000000000000000
  Offset in Bytes: 2685403136

    Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
    ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  * Volume 12        EFI          FAT32  Partition    260 MB  Healthy    System


  DISKPART> sel par 3
  Partition 3 is now the selected partition.

  DISKPART> det par
  Partition 3
  Type    : e3c9e316-0b5c-4db8-817d-f92df00215ae
  Hidden  : Yes
  Required: No
  Attrib  : 0X8000000000000000
  Offset in Bytes: 2958032896

  There is no volume associated with this partition.


  DISKPART> sel par 4
  Partition 4 is now the selected partition.

  DISKPART> det par
  Partition 4
  Type    : ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
  Hidden  : No
  Required: No
  Attrib  : 0000000000000000
  Offset in Bytes: 3092250624

    Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
    ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  * Volume 8     C   System       NTFS   Partition    300 GB  Healthy    Boot
  ```

  - I've customized my `WinRE.wim`, which is why it's partition is 2.5GB 
    WinRE partition *must* be a minimum 650MB *(665MB RAW, i.e. `1024*650 = 665`)*